# Green moss(?) growing in succulent soil

Tags: succulents

I recently repotted some succulents into glass pots. I noticed today that there is some green stuff, looks like moss, growing on the inside walls of the pots. What is this? And is it safe? Should I repot these again to get rid of the moss?

[Picture of pot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1jTy.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more likely algal growth because of the glass pot - in sun, algal growth thrives, but will appear even in shade. Its unlikely to cause harm to the plants, but it will proliferate over time, and likely indicates the soil is too damp, especailly if the pot does not have drainage holes. If  there are no drainage holes, it would be better to repot into something which does, especially as you are growing succulents.